# match anything over multiple lines, then a string of text

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have some text I'm searching through looking for a particular attribute, how can I trim text on lines ahead of it:

for example:

```
aoidj
aodifjiao 
<img src="asdf.asdf" id="a1" />
```

`(\n*|(.*\n*))(.*?)src="(.+?)".*` seems as though it should match any new lines or any text with a new line at the end, and then find my `src` attribute, but instead replacing with `\4` gets me my src attribute but still leaves the content on the lines above.

Comment: I read this 3 times and I still can't comprehend exactly what you want.

Comment: @JoeSimmons match on anything until `src`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following expression:

```
(?:[^s]|src="([^"]*)".*)*
```

and replace with `$1`.

This expression matches either a character that is not an `s` using `[^s]`, or it matches `src` and what follows it, by applying a star `*` to the entire group this starts by matching anything that is not an `s` until if finds the only thing that starts with an `s` and which we care for which is `src`.

Now it captures the value of `src` into group 1, then matches everything after it using `.*`.

So now everything is matches and the value of the `src` attribute is captured in `$1`.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aH1xJ5)

Comment: Sniffer, that works great, can you break it down a little bit for me please. Thanks so much.

Comment: @thomas I have modified my answer, please check edit.

Comment: I see. How could I make this dynamic though. Like, if I don't know if I'll be searching for src or id or rurl?

Comment: if I do `(?:[^(src)]|src="([^"]*)".*)*`, I get matches on all the elements before that are `c`'s or `r`'s or `s`'s..

Comment: You could do this: `/[\s\S]+[a-z]+="([^"]+).+[a-z]+="/` that will match the second to last attribute, regardless of name.

Comment: Seriously though, I would just parse that into HTML and use DOM methods on it. SO much easier.

Comment: @thomas If you are gonna be using this to work with HTML in general, then please **DON NOT**. Use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: yeah,yeah..everybody says that, but I can use it for practice and it's not going to end the world.

Comment: @thomas Well don't practice with HTML, it's not about the end of the world but it is the wrong thing to do and in real applications you won't be using regex to parse HTML.